# Equivalent of mvc:default-servlet-handler in Spring annotation-based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to have the equivalent of `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` defined in an `AnnotationConfig(Web)ApplicationContext`? Right now I have:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/mvc-resources.xml")
class AppConfig {
  // Other configuration...
}
```

with just the following in my `resources/mvc-resources.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans>
```

And it works as expected. Is it possible to do this without importing an XML file? It would be a nice way to cut down on some boilerplate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a bit deeper, I found out that this is a known problem and is addressed by annotation features in the upcoming [Spring 3.1](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/17/spring-3-1-m1-featurespec/).

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
@Configuration
@Import(FeatureConfig.class)
class AppConfig {
   ...
}

@FeatureConfiguration
class FeatureConfig {
  @Feature
  public MvcDefaultServletHandler defaultHandler() {
    return new MvcDefaultServletHandler();
  }
}
```

This does require using the milestone version of spring, though, but it seems to be the cleanest and preferred way of handling this.

Comment: Note that as of M2 they've dropped @Feature in favour of individual @Enable* annotations.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using Spring 3.1 with WebMvc, you can configure default servlet handling like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it out of the box, but you can probably copy [what `DefaultServletHandlerBeanDefinitionParser` does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web.servlet/3.0.4/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/DefaultServletHandlerBeanDefinitionParser.java): Create a Bean of type [`DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.html) and map it to the URL scheme `/**`.

I'd say your Bean should subclass `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` and do the mapping [in a `@PostConstruct` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler defaultServletHttpRequestHandler() {
  return new DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler();
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
  Map<String, String> urlMap = new ManagedMap<String, String>();
  urlMap.put("/**", defaultServletHandlerName);

  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping hm = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
  hm.setUrlMap(urlMap);
  return hm;
}
```

Comment: Where do I get `defaultServletHandlerName` from?

Comment: Also, the `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` seems to take priority over my handler, so that serving static files works, but my own defined paths don't.