# Interceptor for not existing request mapping with java configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-4

I have a configuration class, which extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and I have added interceptors like this:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
}
```

where `myInterceptor()` is:

```
@Bean
public MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
    return new MyInterceptor();
}
```

and it works fine for any mapping (`/api/**`) which I have implemented for example `/api/sample` - preHandle from MyInterceptor is fired (I have a Controller with mapping `/api/sample`).

When I call not existing resource for example `/api/forward/sample` preHandle from MyInterceptor is never called.

Please notice it worked as expected when I had the config in xml, like:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/api/**" />
        <bean class="my.pack.MyInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

For some reason with java configuration requests for not existing mappings are not intercepted. Why the configuration is not equivalent? I thought it should be.

**EDIT:**

A bit more debugging information. With xml configuration `DispatcherServlet#handlerMappings` contains 5 handlers:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
```

with Java configuration it contains 7 handlers:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
```

The problem seems to be with `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` (at least it seems to be used for the resource I call - `api/forward/sample` while for `api/sample` `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is in use) which has empty adoptedIterceptors in the case with Java based configuration.

**EDIT 2:**

Full source code for sample application (I tried to make it as small as possible just to demonstrate the effect):
https://github.com/szprutamich/spring-demo

In class `ConfigurationBase` - configuration can be switched from xml based to java based with static field `CONFIG`.

With xml based config both urls work:

```
/api/sample
/api/forward/sample
```

With java based config forward does not work.

Comment: Can you share actual URLs that pass and relevant web.xml snippet?

Comment: Please check my last edit. Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is about a "not existing request mapping", but in your XML configuration, it exists :

`<default-servlet-handler xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" />`

This declares a default handler for all requests, and a request interceptor ony works if a valid handler is found. Remove this line and you will get the same behavior in both XML and Java configs : no default handler will be found and the interceptor won't work.

So for the interceptor to work on all requests in your Java configuration, you have to declare a default handler. You could override `configureDefaultServletHandling` but afaik it's not possible to configure interceptors on it. You may have to explicitly map `/**` in a default handling controller.

Comment: I have:
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
}
which should does it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062586/equivalent-of-mvcdefault-servlet-handler-in-spring-annotation-based-configurati

Comment: Problem is, this does not automatically add interceptors to it, unlike the XML counterpart. You could provide your own default handler then use getMapping().addInterceptor on it but it's overkill imho, just map /** and it will work.

Comment: @mazter from the doc of addInterceptors : `Override this method to add Spring MVC interceptors for pre- and post-processing of controller invocation.` => "of controller invocation", not of all requests